# Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler is not called

Tags: php, poco-libraries

I'm creating a http server with Poco. like this

```
Poco::Net::ServerSocket svs(10880);
Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams* pParams = new Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams;
pParams->setKeepAlive(true);
Poco::Net::HTTPServer srv(new RequestHandlerFactory, svs, pParams);
srv.start();
```

and it's Handler part

```
class RequestHandlerFactory: public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory
{
public:
    Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const          Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request)
    {
        cout << "hi!" << endl;

        if (request.getURI() == "/test")
            cout << endl << "test!" << endl;
        else
        {
            cout << endl << request.getURI() << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

it works well when I get this server through webbrowsers. but it never works when a php page redirects. like this

```
//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the poco server ip
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10880/test'>";
```

or
    echo " document.location.href='http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10880/test'; 
";

or
    echo "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10880/test'>";

I don't see the "hi". Should I set more things for it? or should I use other classes? not Poco::Net::HTTPServer?

Answer (score 1):

Factory should create and return pointer to `HTTPRequestHandler` (which actually handles the request), not just return 0. Here's an [example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/HTTPTimeServer/src/HTTPTimeServer.cpp).